# Display data with whereRaw clause

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.4

This question is about how do I display the return data in the datatables from 2019-04-01 only.

I tried the whereRaw clause but it doesn't work on how I want it to be.

Here is the code:

```
 case 'total_bets':
                $data = $user->bets()->with(['team', 'match' => function($query)
                    {
                        $query->select('id', 'name', 'status', 'team_winner');
                    }, 'league' => function($query)
                    {
                        $query->select('id', 'name', 'status', 'betting_status', 'league_winner');
                    }])->whereRaw("date(bets.created_at) >= '2019-04-01'")->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');

                return \Datatables::of($data)->addColumn('potential_winnings', function (\App\Bet $bet) use($user)
                })->make(true);
```

Any ideas how to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's Carbon library for same.
In you controller, add Carbon library using:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Eg.

```
$date = Carbon::create(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, '{what-ever-timezone}');
$data = $user->bets()->with(['team', 'match' => function($query) use ($date)
                    {
                        $query->select('id', 'name', 'status', 'team_winner');
                    }, 'league' => function($query)
                    {
                        $query->select('id', 'name', 'status', 'betting_status', 'league_winner');
                    }])->where('bets.created_at', '>=', $date)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');

                return \Datatables::of($data)->addColumn('potential_winnings', function (\App\Bet $bet) use($user)
                })->make(true);
```